# HTML Special Characters & Removing Semi Colon

Tags: php, string, str-replace, htmlspecialchars

So say I had the below varriable

```
$str = Brand Name;&trade; SubBrand Name
```

And I wanted it to display as 
Brand Name™ SubBrand Name

So basically I'm trying to figure out a way to decode html entities (Any of them) and remove extra semi colons / colons from the string.

```
$str = 'Brand Name;&trade; SubBrand Name';
$str = htmlspecialchars_decode($str);
$str = str_replace(';', '', $str);
echo $str;
```

Assuming this is how my string is going to look, what is the best way to go about this?

Comment: First replace ";&" with "&" and _then_ decode the html entities (assuming no consecutive entities).

Comment: The additional semicolons are not related to the entities, unless you've got some broken code mistakenly adding them.

Comment: Thats part of the string not the entity. Thats what i am asking. How can remove the semi colon or if its a colon and not damage the entities, if any in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost have it.  Use `html_entity_decode()` instead, replace, then `htmlentities()` to encode again:

```
$str = 'Brand Name;&trade; SubBrand Name';
$str = html_entity_decode($str);
$str = str_replace(';', '', $str);
$str = htmlentities($str);
echo $str;
```

Comment: I tired your above code and it didn't work for me. Any ideas why?

Comment: No, I get Brand Name™ SubBrand Name

Comment: Don't ask me why, but this seems to work in php 5.4+ but not on php 5.3 or 5.2. By the way, the last step is only necessary if your document is not utf-8.

Comment: That would make since. Im running 5.2

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the hard coded values . Have you tried using the `'&amp;'` which is the decoded result of "&". Htmlentity should have been worked to convert this  .